# How to Kick a Sitecore User Programmatically

Tags: user-management

I tried to Kick a Sitecore user using the command below, but it seems it does not work

```
Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DomainAccessGuard.Kick(sessionID);
```

Even if I passed the current session ID, it does not kick the Sitecore User Out, 
Any ideias?

I got the Sessions with the following command

```
"DomainAccessGuard.Sessions"
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked that the `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` count goes down after the kick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking to the community and parsing the decompiled DLL
I reached the conclusion that Sitecore Kick Method is only used to Free Sitecore License, not to Logout a Sitecore user from the session. In order to achieve that I would need to create some additional method to kill the IIS Session

Thanks all for the support on this ticket

Answer (score 0):

The code to kick all users :

```
foreach(Session session in DomainAccessGuard.Sessions) 
{ 
    DomainAccessGuard.Kick(session.SessionID); 
}
```

**Update**: Domain access guard manages license slots, not authentication. So after you kick  a session auth cookies and sitecore user ticket remain valid and on the next request user get logged in automatically and occupies free license slot.

Comment: I don't think that wouldn't work - the Kick method is expecting a `sessionID` - not the user name.

Comment: Hi, the parameter is "sessionID", I tried with UserName, but it does not work.  if I get the Sessions just after the Kick, that session will not be returned, so, it seems that worked, but the user can continue work on Sitecore, and the session will be live again. So, the Kick command does not kick the user with sessionId or Username Parameter

Comment: Based on that comment - it sounds like the user has the `Remember Me` box ticked and they are just creating a new session on the next request. The kick user doesn't do anything on the users browser to indicate to them that they have been kicked. It just removes their session.

Comment: Hi, the "remember me" check box is not marked as well

Comment: Would adding a Session.Abandon() to the mix not solve the issue of automatic reauthentication?

Comment: HI @MarkCassidy i will try that and let you know , thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Hi @MarkCassidy, unfortunately, the object Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DomainAccessGuard.Session does not contain ".Abandon()"

Comment: I think @MarkCassidy was referring to `HttpContext.Session.Abandon();`