# Single Session per user (session revocation)

Tags: authentication, content-management, shared-session

I am trying to achieve one session per user for content management on XP9.3, understand that there don't seem to be an OOTB solution for this.

So if a user have previously logged in on chrome onto content management, and subsequently logged in on another device, I would like to revoke the session the earlier chrome session. How can I achieve this programmatically on a paid license.

[How to Kick a Sitecore User Programmatically](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/how-to-kick-a-sitecore-user-programmatically) mentioned that the DomainAccessGuard.Kick(sessionID) only works for free sitecore license which would not work for my paid version.

[Sitecore 10 - Single Login Session and Kick Idle User](https://edwenkerk.hashnode.dev/sitecore-10-single-login-session-and-kick-idle-user) mentioned using DomainAccessGuard.Kick(sessionID) together with BaseTicketManager.RemoveTicket(ticketID) method but seems to be implementation for a free licensing version as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second article you mentioned is just what you need.

When they mention "free Sitecore license" they don't mean license that you don't have to pay for.

What they mean is that with paid Sitecore license you have only limited number of concurrent users who can be logged in to Sitecore Content Management in parallel. By "free" license, they mean that you will "release" one of the concurrent slots.

So yes, you should use

```
DomainAccessGuard.Kick(userSession.SessionID);
```

and if that's not enough for you, try working with `TicketManager` like in the article you mentioned.